# Publishing typescript package without ts files?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsconfig

I have a typescript project that I want to publish it, I generate all the js files in a directory called build and all declaration files in a directory called declaration, I don't want to include .ts files in my published version
I was wonder how can I do this without using gulp?

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "declarationDir": "declaration"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "data-layer",
  "version": "1.1.4",
  "description": "data access layer",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "types": "./declaration/index.d.ts",
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.npmignore` file where you tell to ignore all files that are `.ts` but not `.d.ts`

```
*.ts
!*.d.ts
```

More information on npmignore you can find [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply
So I created .npmignore like this:
*.ts
!*.d.ts
build
declaration
!*.log
but it doesn't include the build and declaration directory in the published package

Comment: @user4092086 then most likely they are in your gitignore file. `.npmignore` just extends the list from `.gitignore`

Comment: hmm tried to remove them from .gitignore didn't work again although .npmignore is supposed to override .gitignore

Comment: Sorry my bad in the .npmignore I had build declaration instead of !build and !declaration